# How to show popup dialog over lock screen like Android Alarm Clock when getting GCM

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I need to show message on top of the lock screen,
like Android Alarm Clock is displaying full screen of the alarm, when it's the time to wake up.

Here is a photo of one of the screen popup when there is alarm:

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPrFe.jpg)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Window window = getWindow();

window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
```

Answer (score 2):

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html

You are looking for the method `setFullScreenIntent()`. This allows a notification to display over whatever is being viewed. Remember, this is only for extremely critical notifications (phone call or alarm clock) so only do this if absolutely necessary.

Comment: My intent is open only when I click the notification.
It is not like alarm clock or whatsapp that the window is popping without any click.
This is my code:  
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
        new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.play)
                .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentTitle("Bring me front!")
                .setContentText("Bring me!!! BRING!!!")
                .setFullScreenIntent(contentIntent, true);

Comment: Is it a heads-up notification? From the link: "On some platforms, the system UI may choose to display a heads-up notification, instead of launching this intent, while the user is using the device." This is how it works for all apps.

Comment: Yes, but is there a way to force showing the intent?
I need to display image and I can't do it with notification.
And it always displaying heads-up notification, even if my phone is locked or is idle with screen on..
I'm asking because alarm clock and whatsapp is doing just this.
Thank you @Shadesblade for helping me so much

Comment: If you want to circumnavigate Androids notification handler when the screen is on, you probably need to do something similar to Facebook's chatheads with SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW. I honestly don't know about when the screen is locked, setting setFullScreenIntent() should handle that.

Comment: Here's a small guide for doing something in coordination with SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW: http://androidsrc.net/facebook-chat-like-floating-chat-heads/